# Android : Facing force close while taking data in array

Tags: android

I'm trying to get the data from the user's voice and storing it into a string and then setting that text on to the text view. But my application is getting force closed. Please provide the correct code.
Here's my code:

```
package com.example.voicerecognization;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;  
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class VoiceRecognization extends Activity {

private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1234;
private ListView resultList;
Button speakButton;
TextView tv;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_voice_recognization);

    speakButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    resultList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    // Disable button if no recognition service is present
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(new Intent(
            RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH), 0);
    if (activities.size() == 0) {
        speakButton.setEnabled(false);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recognizer Not Found",
                1000).show();
    }
    speakButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startVoiceRecognitionActivity();
        }
    });
}

private void startVoiceRecognitionActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
            "Rakshak Voice Recognition...");
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        String[] str = data
                .getStringArrayExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

        tv.setText(str[0]);
        /*
         * ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
         * RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS); resultList.setAdapter(new
         * ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
         * matches));
         */
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
}
```

Comment: Please post your complete log cat error

Comment: Problem is resolved i guess no need to give logcat details now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your crash is probably because you're casting an ArrayList as a String array - the call to `data.getStringArrayExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS)` should be `data.getStringArrayListExtra(...)` as you have in your commented code, you can then use the `get(int index)` method to get the first element like so: `matches.get(0)`.

Although you might want to first check to ensure the list has elements in it.

Comment: Thank u, lemme check and will respond to this.